# Вызов функции из std::function

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть примитивный класс:

```
class type
{
   public:
int print(int i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; return i * i; }
void test()
{
    std::function<int(int)> func(std::bind(&type::print, this, 489));
    func(); // как вызвать функцию, ведь в конструкторе я уже передал ей аргумент 489?
}
};
```

Собственно, хотелось бы узнать.

Comment: Возможно вам подойдет более другой вариант: `auto func = [this]() { print(489); }; func();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Должно быть

```
std::function<int()> func(std::bind(&type::print, this, 489));
func();
```

Так как оба параметра вашей функции вы уже "связали", свободных параметров больше нет и внешний интерфейс вашего функтора - `int()`, а не `int(int)`.

Конструктор `std::function` не контролирует соответствие интерфейса вызова между тем типом, который вы указали в `<...>`, и тем функтором, который вы передали в качестве параметра. Соответствие ищется только в момент самого вызова. Поэтому в вашем варианте вы и получаете ошибку именно на строчку `func();`, а не при инициализации `func`.

Более того, в вашем исходном варианте вы можете вызвать ваш `func`, как

```
func(42);
```

и все прекрасно скомпилируется. Функциональный объект, создаваемый `std::bind` не против того, чтобы ему передавали лишние аргументы - он их просто игнорирует.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо! Действительно, теперь всё работает.

Comment: @Range, тогда примите ответ нажав на галочку рядом с ним. Вы вроде бы не первый день на сайте, должны знать что тут к чему.

Comment: @ixSci ответ можно было принять через 10 минут, увы, я просто уснул.